# Normalize two or more sound signals in order to let them with the same duration time and amplitude

Tags: signal-analysis, sound, octave, sound-recognition

I am very new in signal processing area and I am trying to solve the task in order to make an experiment with audio files from different languages, so, I am trying to let some ogg audio files with the same amplitude(wave height) and playing duration, so that the first wave can have the same amplitude from the second one.duration

My file:
[image]

Original file(The file that I am wanting to convert the previous file to the format of this file):
[image]

Any ideas in how could I begin on it? I am using Octave, or any algorithm to it in any other language (Python, MATLAB, Scala)?

Comment: **Equalize** is not a poerper term here, which may better be replaced by **scaled**,**stretched**, and/or **normalized**...

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that, thanks for this advice, is because my research advisor at the beginning asked that the attribute that he wanted that I would like that I fit in the code would be the amplitude/height... Now I'm googling here and I am finding some codes with normalization! I'm gonna modify the title of the doubt to let more clear, thanks!!

Comment: How about the amplitude/height/peak, it would be the same as the volume of it isn't it??

Comment: A good start would be to extract the amplitude envelope of the first signal, and then adjust the envelope of the second signal to match. One could try uniform scaling along time based on onset/offset as well. Though if this is good enough to be useful I dont know